# tilestache Provider() layer object? Can the referring URL be obtained?

Tags: python, tilestache

Following the example [here](https://github.com/zain/pycon2012/blob/master/maps/tileserver/provider.py), I'm attempting to create a layer for display using tilestache.  Is there a way to get the referring url?

I can't seem to find any documentation of what the `layer` object is.
I suspect there may be something in this object that I can use...

```
class BaselineLayerProvider(object):
    def __init__(self, layer, *args, **kwargs):
        self.layer = layer
        self.provider = ModestMaps.OpenStreetMap.Provider()                

    def renderArea(self, width, height, srs, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zoom):
        print self.layer
        print dir(self.layer)

        # first, figure out the bounding box of the tile we're rendering
        nw = self.layer.projection.projLocation(ModestMaps.Core.Point(xmin, ymin))
        se = self.layer.projection.projLocation(ModestMaps.Core.Point(xmax, ymax))
        max_lat = max(nw.lat, se.lat)
        min_lat = min(nw.lat, se.lat)
        max_lon = max(nw.lon, se.lon)
        min_lon = min(nw.lon, se.lon)

        bbox = Polygon.from_bbox((min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat))
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The Layer object is described here: http://tilestache.org/doc/#layers

I haven't provided a way to get the HTTP referer. If you need to add this feature, you can create and use an alternate WSGI server of your own. We have a few examples of this in the Tilestache source, such as this example:

https://github.com/migurski/TileStache/blob/master/TileStache/Goodies/ExternalConfigServer.py

Comment: Thanks!  It wasn't initially clear that the layer object was the object defined in the "tilestache.cfg" file.

Comment: My initial thought was to use the URL as a method to perform displayed layer filtering.  After digging in a little more I found that updating the tilestache.cfg with the layers dynamically and giving the url for the config in the wsgi file solved my problem.